# Laravel + Elixir: importing bootstrap less error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gulp, laravel-elixir

I've installed bootstrap with bower into `/vendor/bower_components` folder. Also I have an app.less file with this import:

`@import '/vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap';`

For the time being it worked, when I run `gulp` I got public.css compiled and everything went good. However, I've reinstall npm/nvm/gulp/bower and such stuff and after then I got an error when running `gulp`:

`[15:19:07] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Less Compilation Failed!: '/vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' wasn't found. Tried - /vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less in file /var/www/rld/resources/assets/less/app.less line no. 1`

Actually it works if I remove `/` (backslash) from the import path, but I don't quite understand what path should be used in my main app.less. It worked before but right now is broken, however on my another computer it works fine (not sure if I reinstall gulp what will happen). So I'm confused what path I should use for importing bootstrap less files.

Answer (score 2):

See also https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#options and then especially the `paths` option.

When you us the import path without the leading `/` (`@import '/vendor/`) the compiler will search relative from `app.less` (`less/vendor`). With a leading `/` it will try to find the file in the `/vendor/` folder on your system (absolute path).

Comment: I'm just confused why the behaviour has changed. It always worked with leading "/", like if I have /var/www/myproject and used @import "/vendor/bower_components..", gulp always search in the project root dir. Anyway, I'm not that experienced with gulp, I use laravel elixir, how can I change the path option? Thanks by the way :)

Answer (score -1):

You may change your app.less @import as follow:

```
@import "../../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
```

Works for us