# Ignore less imports afterwards

Tags: css, gulp, less, laravel-elixir

I want to use bootstrap and customize it via less. My main less file looks like this:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "custom-bootstrap-variables";
```

The `bootstrap.less` also contains multiple imports. Is it possible to "ignore" some imports in the `bootstrap.less`, for example `well.less` **without** altering the original `bootstap.less`.

Something like:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "custom-bootstrap-variables";
@ignore "bootstrap/well"
```

Comment: I would say the answer is simply no.

Comment: AFAIK no it isn't possible. There a [few options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options) but none of them is relevant

Comment: Copy the original bootstrap file with all the imports and delete those you don't want. Then you use that custom file instead of bootstrap's.

Comment: Maybe if you'd want to import that well only once and other files are already importing it, then you could use `(once)` but I doubt its your use case :) `(reference)` is cool and useful when you want to use `variables.less` and `mixins.less` in many LESS files (your page loads 2 CSS: bootstrap.css and then my-styles.less: both should use and share the same variables and mixins)

Comment: So there is no way? My goal is to make an update as easy as possible. When doing all the imports myself, I have to check again if there is a new bootstrap version and what imports might have changed.

Comment: Several questions: 1) Can you say more about what isn't easy about updating? `@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";` won't be messed up by changes to bootstrap - Bootstrap should handle all of its internal `@import`s fine without you having to do anything. 2) Why don't you want import some parts of Bootstrap? Knowing that will help us figure out the best thing for you to do. 3) What does this have to do with `laravel-elixir`? Is it possible you're having some problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650069/laravel-elixir-importing-bootstrap-less-error?rq=1 ?

Comment: 1) When I do not use the main bootstrap.less, I will have to import all the components myself. What if something changes, like, they remove a component completely? 2) I want to save space by not including components I do not use. 3) I am using elixir to compile the stuff, maybe there is way.

Comment: 1) You can keep using the version of Bootstrap that works for you :) This is common practice, and part of the reason the people who make Bootstrap give it a version number: they want to make sure people know when their are big changes (google "semver" and "breaking change"). 2) @FelipeAls has the right solution for this: you can use a LESS reference import. The LESS documentation actually uses a Bootstrap example http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference and Chris Coyier has a good write-up https://css-tricks.com/reference-imports-in-less-are-kinda-cool/